# Need to know the tables inwhich data got entered by user action

Tags: sql

I have a database created in SQL 2008.
I have all the required tables.
A user is doing some action due to which entries are going in some tables.
I need to know in what all table entries are done by a particular user action.
Can we write some query for the same?

Comment: Add tables for useraccess..add their id onto other forms which you want to trace what their doing.

Comment: Do you mean **data auditing**? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaroslav.I exactly meant data auditing

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean data auditing? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx – Jaroslav Jandek